# crud angular spring boot 500 duplicate

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, crud

i am trying to edit chambre report
this is list of reports :
[image: report list]

when i click modifier i go to other route with id in path and also the data on form
[image: update form]

but i change a feild and click on button i receive error 500 :
[image: spring boot code :]

[image: angular error 500]

this is controller spring boot :

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<MaintenanceRoomReport> updateReport(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody MaintenanceRoomReport m) {
    MaintenanceRoomReport updatedReport = reportService.editReport(id, m);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedReport);
}
```

this is code reportform :

```
  this.reportForm = new FormGroup({
      chambre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      problem: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(''),
      dateReport: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

and from the Postman format should be like that :

```
{
    "chambre":{
        "idChambre" : "1"
    },
    "problem":"BINOME",
    "description":"i am trying to change this",
    "dateReport":"2023-12-07"
}
```

Comment: Well, the exception clearly states you have SQL constraint violation.  Angular implementation is good, your problem is here - `reportService.editReport(id, m)`. Please share the service implementation (and possibly DAO).

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the form is `http://localhost:4200/reporting/update/{id}`.

The URL that returns HTTP 500 error code is `http://localhost:8088/reported/update`.  That seems odd to me.  Shouldn't the domain be the same for both?  Why are the ports different?

Can you run the listener on port 8088 in a debugger?  Setting a breakpoint to learn the precise reason for the HTTP 500 server error seems helpful.

Comment: hello sir as i can see the path on console is : http://localhost:4200/reporting/update/11 
the problem it's trying to add new one not updating it

Comment: I'd have to look at your code to be able to tell when it knows that modifying the primary key value should mean "create a new one, don't update the one you have with the old id".  If your code doesn't have that logic in it, I'd guess that's your problem.

Comment: duffymo thank you sir , for ports one for spring boot ( 8088 ) and 4200 is for angular services

Comment: I'd advise that you run your Spring Boot service locally in an IDE like IntelliJ.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see what's causing the HTTP 500 error.  You might want to think about improving your exception handling and logging so you can tell when an error occurs without having to set a breakpoint.